# How do I specify/increase CPU usage for a TFjob served on KubeFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow

I have a GKE setup running KubeFlow on the latest versions with Kustomize. The master TFJob pulls a Docker image of the full model and runs it. I'm running into a simple issue where I wish to increase the amount of CPU usage but can't seem to do it.

Is this something I need to specify in the Docker model code, in the Kubernetes configuration, in the TFJob yamls, or somewhere else?

I've tried specifying a minimum size & limit for cpu resources for the container. I also tried specifying those for the master pod but it doesn't seem to update.

There also isn't much documentation or many similar questions on this.

Comment: You should look into requests: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/

Comment: Thanks, I checked it out but it doesn't solve the issue. It's what I used to initially increase the size of the container. It requisitioned more resources but did not actually use them.

Comment: Hi it's not clear what you are asking about. It's problem with specify a CPU request and a CPU limit or with customizing resources from Kubeflow deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to [Customizing the TFJob](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/training/tftraining/#customizing-the-tfjob)

And yes, it is set in your TFJob yaml. the code snippets:

```
resources:
          limits:
            cpu: '1'
```